# C++ pointer use for persistent objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I am developing a game using C++. I've read in a lot of places that using pointers in C++ should basically be avoided at all costs. I am still learning C++ and slightly confused by this.

I would like a player object that is persistent and lives for the duration of the game session. This object will contain the players inventory, player stats etc etc.

The player's inventory is basically just a vector containing item objects (an 'Item' class I've created).

If someone can clarify the following it would clear up my confusion:

1. When people say 'pointers are bad' do they mean standard C++ pointers? Are smart pointers deemed 'ok'?
2. How else could I access persistant objects allocated on the heap other than a pointer?
3. If I want a method that finds an item in the players inventory, but returns NULL if the item is not found, how else can that be implemented without pointers? Since the item returned from 'findItem' should be editable (to change the items count for instance), at the moment I return a pointer to the item in the vector. Is this a valid use of pointers?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you've read should probably read "using *resource owning raw pointers* should be avoided at all costs." instead.

Comment: Sorry, since I'm still learning C++, what exactly does that mean?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: no, it's a smart pointer that owns a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, *raw*, C-style pointers are considered bad. Smart pointers are OK. There are situations where you **need** to use (smart) pointers - collections of polymorphic objects for example: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IObject> >`.
2. A persistent object doesn't have to be on the heap. It can be an object with static storage duration or even an automatic object that lives *just long enough* - i.e. you create it in `main()`.
3. Numerous ways - you can throw an exception (probably too harsh) or go the `std` way an return an iterator - similar to `.end()`.

Comment: Ok I understand a bit better now. Your point number 2: do you mean say creating the object and just not letting it fall out of scope? ie. passing the object around as needed?

Comment: @ThisDarkTao that's what I mean (but it's just an example, it probably doesn't apply to your particular situation though)

Comment: Ah right I see. I also didn't realise you could return an iterator. I'll use that solution to that problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would recommend to use shared pointers (either from boost or from std). Do not use raw pointers. C++ has also other smart pointers like auto_ptr, but almost nobody is using them today.
If you want to allocate something on the heap, do:

```
std::shared_ptr<ClassA> A(new ClassA());
```

This is more secure than using raw pointers. When you are going out of scope, the shared pointer will assure you that the object it is pointing to will be destroyed. Raw pointers are not doing this, meaning that you have to destroy everything yourself manually